# is python using iso-8859-1 and utf-8 at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, diacritics

```
kh@lara:~/tmp $ python 
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> str = 'äöü'
>>> len(str)
3
>>> ord(str[0])
228
>>> ord(str[1])
246
>>> ord(str[2])
252
>>> ord(str[3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>> f = open ('uml.txt', 'w')
>>> f.write(str)
3
>>> f.close()
>>> 
kh@lara:~/tmp $ hexdump uml.txt
0000000 a4c3 b6c3 bcc3                         
0000006
```

Can somebody explain this? 228, 246, 252 is 'äöü' in iso-8859-1.

doc.python.org: ord(c)
Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97 and ord('€') (Euro sign) returns 8364. This is the inverse of chr().

Comment: Unicode happens to correspond to ISO-8859-1 for these characters. See [Unicode code chart U0080](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) (PDF) and [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). When you write to a file, Python uses UTF-8 encoding, therefore you get what you see when you hexdump the file.